# What is this error and how do I therefore display top 5 scores from a .csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I'm writing a dice game, and after the game ends, both players' names are saved to `leaderboard2.csv` file. From `leaderboard2.csv`, I'm trying to display top 5 scores. How is this done?

I watched many tutorials but they all use `.txt` files, whereas I have a `.csv` file (in Excel) for the leader board.

I'm using python 3.3.4 and my code is right below:

```py
import operator
with open("leaderboard2.csv", "r") as l:
    try:
        sort_key = operator.itemgetter(0)
        split_lines = (line.split(None, 1) for line in l) # splits the file into it's individual lines
        numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines) # splits the numbers and the letters
        score = sorted(numeric_lines, key=sort_key, reverse=True) # sorts the numbers and letters into the opposite order
        leader_board1 = (score[0])
        leader_board2 = (score[1])
        leader_board3 = (score[2])
        leader_board4 = (score[3])
        leader_board5 = (score[4]) # gets the fifth line
    except IndexError:
        leader_board1 = '\n'
        leader_board2 = '\n'
        leader_board3 = '\n'
        leader_board4 = '\n'
        leader_board5 = '\n'
        print("--------- LEADER BOARD ---------")
        sys.stdout.write("FIRST PLACE: "), print(*leader_board1, sep=" points: ", end='')
        sys.stdout.write("SECOND PLACE: "), print(*leader_board2, sep=" points: ", end='\n')
        sys.stdout.write("THIRD PLACE: "), print(*leader_board3, sep=" points: ", end='')
        sys.stdout.write("FOURTH PLACE: "), print(*leader_board4, sep=" points: ", end='')
        sys.stdout.write("FIFTH PLACE: "), print(*leader_board5, sep=" points: ", end='')
        input(">>> ")
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
numeric_lines = ((int(line[0]), line[1]) for line in split_lines) # splits the numbers and the letters
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ok,46'
```

By the way, `ok,46` is the first row in the `.csv` file (`ok` is the user name, `46` is the score)

1) What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

2) How else can I display top 5 scores from the `.csv` file?

My cvs file looks like this:

```
k,32
no,75
test,33
example,65
a,10
l,50
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: second place has a `end='\n'` at the end of your write, is that intentional? the error you are getting means that you tried to pass the string `'ok,46'` to `int()` meaning `line[0]` failed to split as you expect it to. split without a `sep` splits on white space, as you can see `'ok,46'` has no white space, so either add a space there or split on a `,`(comma)

Comment: It tells you right there in the message. You cannot call `int()` on the string `'ok,46'`

Comment: Thank you , i've fixed the errors but the code doesnt work at all :( . Is there another way of displaying the top 5 scores from my csv file?

Comment: Can you edit your original post and show a sample of what your .csv looks like?

Comment: i dont know how to attach files but i'll print screen

Comment: `int(line[0])` is your problem, without the file I can only guess that `int(line[3:]) ` will work but its hard coded for this case. `line.split(",", 1)` might help more.

Comment: also, there will be times where there may not be 5 people's score, how do I display top 3 for example if there are only 3 people in the leaderboard

Comment: use a loop based on the number of rows in the file

Comment: I've attached the csv file as well now, just need something that displays top 5 scores, or if there arent 5 players in the leaderboard, however many people there are in the leaderboard, display that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see your CSV file. You don't have to take a screenshot or upload any files or anything, just copy-and-paste a few lines of text from your CSV file.

Comment: sorry about that, you can see it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using Python 3.6+ and its standard modules:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

csvfile = Path('leaderboard2.csv')

with csvfile.open() as f:
    scores = Counter(dict(csv.reader(f)))

    # convert scores into integers
    # (there are better ways but I'm being didactic)
    for name in scores:
        scores[name] = int(scores[name])

    # list the top five
    for name, score in scores.most_common(5):
        print(f'{name}: {score}')
```

Here is an alternative version:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

csvfile = Path('leaderboard2.csv')

scores = Counter()

with csvfile.open() as f:
    for name,score in csv.reader(f):

    # convert score into integer
    score = int(score)
    scores[name] = score

# list the top five
for name, score in scores.most_common(5):
    print(f'{name}: {score}')
```

And here is a version that will work with earlier versions of Python 3:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

scores = Counter()

with open('leaderboard2.csv') as f:
    for name,score in csv.reader(f):

    # convert score into integer
    score = int(score)
    scores[name] = score

# list the top five
for name, score in scores.most_common(5):
    print('%s: %s' % (name, score))
```

I hope it helps as starting point.

Comment: accdias thank you for the codes. However, on both codes, there is an invalid syntax on the last line. How do I fix the error?

Comment: it says before the last bracket on the last lines of both codes and after the last apostrophe

Comment: That's an `f-string` and it requires Python 3.6+. I will edit the answer and post an alternative version. Check [PEP498](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498).

Comment: If possible, mark the answer as accepted. That will help other people with the same question.

Comment: Thanks again. It says no module called pathlib. Is this because of my version of python?

Comment: [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is available on Python 3.4+. If you have an earlier version, you can replace that with `open()`, the same way you are used to.